# Make registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE persistently read-only

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry, readonly, regedit

Hello a few days ago I wanted to rename "ProcessorName" in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ HARDWARE \ DESCRIPTION \ System \ CentralProcessor \ 0.
```

I succeeded, but every time the system was rebooted, windows reverted the changes I made.

With SubACL, I changed the owner of the registry keys to the administrator group, but it still didn't work.

I also tried to put a .reg file to

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

But I dont want this, as I'm creating a program that allows renaming your CPU name.

I guess if I make this key is "read only", the system cannot change it, it just reads it.

How can I make that happen with  cmd, powershell, etc. (without opening `regedit`)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like there are no way to make that.

Comment: @BaconBits, sounds like your comment is worthy of being turned into an answer.

Comment: Good point, @Compo; I've edited the title accordingly - itsReinsy, I hope that reflects your intent.

Comment: I just did some perusing in the registry and my renamed, via Settings->System, machine name shows up in a lot of keys. You might try a registry monitoring program and then change your computers name via the indicated method and see what changes. Most likely a lot more registry entries than you want to mess with. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can ever get a change to survive a reboot by design. As far as I'm aware, HKLM\HARDWARE is volatile data. My understanding is that the entire key is deleted and recreated at each boot by ntdetect.com scanning the system for hardware. So I don't believe that it's going to matter if you make it read only.

Even if my understanding above is incorrect, ntdetect.com is run by the NT bootloader (NTLDR) before execution has been passed off to the NT kernel (ntoskrnl.exe). Hardware detection runs before the NT kernel has loaded because the kernel needs the list of installed hardware before it can load. I would be surprised if it would respect a write-deny ACLs. I think this is before the security system is even available.

All I can think you could do would be to create a script or program that executes at startup or login to rename the value, but I guess I don't see the purpose in that.